# Rock Paper Scissors in console repeating issue

Tags: javascript

Trying to play a game of RPS 3 times in the console with an updating score and result. Running it outside of the game function works fine for the first game, but running the functions multiple times in the game function leaves my result to not update properly.

Tried returning result from the playRound function than putting the result through a score function. Thought that the result function would update every time I call it in the game function.
Instead, it doesn't update and I get the same result as the first round played no matter the difference in outcomes from the choices made. Would love input on how I can get the result to update.

```js
let computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
let randomNum = Math.random();
function getComputerChoice() {
  let randomNum = Math.random()
  let computerSelection = '';
  if (randomNum >= 0 && randomNum < 1 / 3) {
    computerSelection = 'rock';
  } else if (randomNum >= 1 / 3 && randomNum < 2 / 3) {
    computerSelection = 'paper';
  } else if (randomNum >= 2 / 3 && randomNum < 1) {
    computerSelection = 'scissors';
  }
  console.log(computerSelection);
  return computerSelection
}
// prompt the player to make a selection
let playerSelection = getPlayerChoice()
function getPlayerChoice() {
  let playerSelection = prompt('Rock, Paper, or Scissors?').toLowerCase();
  if (playerSelection === 'rock') {
    console.log('rock');
  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper') {
    console.log('paper');
  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors') {
    console.log('scissors');
  }
  return playerSelection
}
// compare the player selection to the comp selection and update a score
let result = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  let result = '';
  if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
    result = 'Tie Game!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
    result = `Computer wins! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;
  } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
    result = 'You win! Computer sucks!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
    result = 'You win! Computer sucks!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
    result = 'Tie Game!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
    result = `Computer wins! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection} `;
  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
    result = `Computer wins! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;
  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
    result = 'You win! Computer sucks!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
    result = 'Tie Game!';
  };
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

let score = {
  wins: 0,
  losses: 0,
};

function updateScore(result) {
  if (result === 'You win! Computer sucks!') {
    score.wins += 1;
  } else if (result === 'Tie Game!') {
    score = score;
  } else if (result === `Computer wins! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`) {
    score.losses += 1;
  };
  console.log(score)
  return score;
};

updateScore(result);

function game() {
  getPlayerChoice();
  getComputerChoice();
  playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
  updateScore(result);
  getPlayerChoice();
  getComputerChoice();
  playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
  updateScore(result);
};

game();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your game function:

The problem is that your `getComputerChoice` and `playRound` returns a value, but you never assign that value.

Should be:

```
function game() {
  getPlayerChoice();
  computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
  result = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
  updateScore(result);
  getPlayerChoice();
  computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
  result = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
  updateScore(result);
};
```

**Demo**

```js
let computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
let randomNum = Math.random();

function getComputerChoice() {
  let randomNum = Math.random()
  let computerSelection = '';
  if (randomNum >= 0 && randomNum < 1 / 3) {
    computerSelection = 'rock';
  } else if (randomNum >= 1 / 3 && randomNum < 2 / 3) {
    computerSelection = 'paper';
  } else if (randomNum >= 2 / 3 && randomNum < 1) {
    computerSelection = 'scissors';
  }
  console.log(computerSelection);
  return computerSelection
}
// prompt the player to make a selection
let playerSelection = getPlayerChoice()

function getPlayerChoice() {
  let playerSelection = prompt('Rock, Paper, or Scissors?').toLowerCase();
  if (playerSelection === 'rock') {
    console.log('rock');
  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper') {
    console.log('paper');
  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors') {
    console.log('scissors');
  }
  return playerSelection
}
// compare the player selection to the comp selection and update a score
let result = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  let result = '';
  if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
    result = 'Tie Game!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
    result = `Computer wins! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;
  } else if (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
    result = 'You win! Computer sucks!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
    result = 'You win! Computer sucks!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
    result = 'Tie Game!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
    result = `Computer wins! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection} `;
  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'rock') {
    result = `Computer wins! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;
  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'paper') {
    result = 'You win! Computer sucks!';
  } else if (playerSelection === 'scissors' && computerSelection === 'scissors') {
    result = 'Tie Game!';
  };
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

let score = {
  wins: 0,
  losses: 0,
};

function updateScore(result) {
  if (result === 'You win! Computer sucks!') {
    score.wins += 1;
  } else if (result === 'Tie Game!') {
    score = score;
  } else if (result === `Computer wins! ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`) {
    score.losses += 1;
  };
  console.log(score)
  return score;
};

updateScore(result);

function game() {
  getPlayerChoice();
  computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
  result = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
  updateScore(result);
  getPlayerChoice();
  computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
  result = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
  updateScore(result);
};

game();
```

Comment: Well this works. However I want to note this is a very quick answer to make it work. There is obvious a lot more wrong in your code aside of some optimizations. OP must realize it's better to contain everything in the function game and call those functions. He did this, however he also did some random calls in between. This is not good and very confusing. OP should consider reformatting so only functions remain and only one call is made: game().

Comment: @Wimanicesir I agree there is a lots of things that could be improved, but I believe that Op is new at coding, so I think it would maybe make it harder for OP to understand if asked or provided with optimized code. I gave of an easy to understand solution so he can learn from it.